# Predicate types supported for partition pruning in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Does Spark (version 1.6.1) support partition pruning for filters other than equality operator (for e.g. >, <, !=, >=, etc.)? This is for parquet data that are partitioned by specific integer column.

Thanks!